# Life cycle of Servlet and its methods

Tags: java, servlets, lifecycle

I know that Servlets consist of the `init`, `service` and `destroy` methods. I also know that there are the `doPost` and `doGet` methods available. The question is how the `service` method relates to the `doPost` and `doGet` methods. Are they called from within the `service` method after the `request` is being identified? Is the `service` omitted when the `do` methods are implemented? I need some clarifications here.

For example in a life cycle of a `Servlet` that receives a single `POST` request, I would have guessed that the order would be:

- `init()` is executed
- when `init()` is finished the `service()` is called
- `service()` identifies the `request` and calls the `doPost()` method
- when both `doPost()` and `service()` finish the `destroy()` method is executed

Would that be right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't right.

`init()` and `destroy()` are called only once. The servlet is instantiated by the container, and its `init()` method is called. That usually happens at startup, or when the first request for the servlet comes in.

Then **all** the requests are handled by the `service()` method, which calls the appropriate `doXxx()` method based on the request type ([as documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html)).

Then, when the application is undeployed (or the server stopped), the `destroy()` method is called.

The javadoc is your friend. Read it. It contains all the answers to your questions. The specifications are also freely available.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation, `service` is responsible for dispatching to the relevant servlet method, based on the *HTTP* method called (*POST*, *GET*...)

> Receives standard HTTP requests from the public service method and
>   dispatches them to the doXXX methods defined in this class. This
>   method is an HTTP-specific version of the
>   Servlet.service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,
>   javax.servlet.ServletResponse) method. There's no need to override
>   this method.

[HTTPServlet.service](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse))

Answer (score 2):

This is the basic flow,
 - The servlet is initialized by calling the init () method.

- The servlet calls service() method to process a client's request.
- The service method invokes the doGet or doPost based on the request
  type came from the client if get request came doGet is invoked if
  post request doPost is invoked
- The servlet is terminated by calling the destroy() method.
- Finally, servlet is garbage collected by the garbage collector of the
  JVM.

The **service() method** is the main method to perform the actual task. The servlet container (i.e. web server) calls the service() method to handle requests coming from the client( browsers) and to write the formatted response back to the client.

Each time the server receives a request for a servlet, the server spawns a new thread and calls service. The service() method checks the HTTP request type (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.) and calls doGet, doPost, doPut, doDelete, etc. methods as appropriate.

Servlet Life Cycle[image]